# Lottie web disappears when loading state of data loading from API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, lottie

Here my lottie component

`import { Box } from '@mui/material';
import Lottie from 'lottie-web';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import notFoundLoadingAnimation from "../../../images/lotiieforNotFoundBaseRoute.json"

```
const BaseNotFoundLottieLoader = (props) => {
    const { height, width } = props
    const anime = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        Lottie.loadAnimation({
            container: anime.current,
            renderer: "svg",
            loop: true,
            autoplay: true,
            animationData: notFoundLoadingAnimation,
        });
    }, []);

    return (
        <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: "center", alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Box data-testid="not-found-animation" className="full-width-height container" style={{ height: height, width: width }} ref={anime}></Box>
        </Box>
    );
};


export default BaseNotFoundLottieLoader;`
```